# Add delimiter in Notepad (.txt file) at specific location line by line. (All Lines are with same Length)

Tags: excel, vba

Add delimiter in text file via Excel VBA macro.
Text file size 210MB with 2.5 Cr rows.
All the lines have same number of characters with same format.

**Original file**

```
 1    0   0-2344562424E-000-3.2344562424E-000-4.5333662424E-000
 2    0   0-1238562424E-000-3.3456562424E-000-7.5333662424E-000
```

**Required file**

```
 1;    0;   0-2344562424E-000;-3.2344562424E-000;-4.5333662424E-000;
 2;    0;   0-1238562424E-000;-3.3456562424E-000;-7.5333662424E-000;
```

---

```
Sub main()

Dim TextFile As Integer

Dim FilePath As String

Dim FileContent As String

  FilePath = "C:\Users\devas\Downloads\New folder\TEST\diskostn.txt"

  TextFile = FreeFile

  Open FilePath For Input As TextFile

  FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)

  Close TextFile


         Debug.Print FileContent

  TextFile = FreeFile

  Open FilePath For Output As TextFile

  Print #TextFile, FileContent

  Close TextFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. Stack Overflow is not actually meant to be a code-writing service. It's expected that you've made some effort to solve this yourself and are stuck. Do you have any code that you've tried that you can share?

Comment: Upload it to a SQL Server and then export it using a delimiter `;`. VBA won't be able to do it with these many rows, probably will get stuck. Even if you try with VBA, ask a question with the code that you have tried.

Comment: Isn't that a job for awk or sed?

Comment: @Mikku, Sir,  Thanks for your suggestion but we need it by VBA.

Comment: @BigBen, Sir I have code to get notepad content, kindly find below,                             Sub main()

Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String

  FilePath = "C:\Users\devas\Downloads\New folder\TEST\diskostn.txt"
  TextFile = FreeFile
  Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
  FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
  Close TextFile
  
         Debug.Print FileContent
  
  TextFile = FreeFile
  Open FilePath For Output As TextFile
  Print #TextFile, FileContent
  Close TextFile

End Sub

Comment: @Storax, sir, I dont know about "awk or sed".

Comment: Many ways to do that? modified simplest way taken by you. it take 550  secs to complete `Sub makedelimtedfile()
Dim Fno As Integer, Fno2 As Integer, i As Long
Dim FilePath As String, FilePath2 As String, xStr As String
Dim Tm As Double, Ln As String
FilePath = "C:\Users\user\desktop\Great.txt"
FilePath2 = "C:\Users\user\desktop\Great2.txt"
Fno = FreeFile
Tm = Timer
Open FilePath For Input As #Fno
Fno2 = FreeFile
Open FilePath2 For Output As #Fno2
i = 1
    Do While Not EOF(Fno)
    Line Input #Fno, Ln`

Comment: `If Len(Ln) >= 62 Then
        Ln = Mid(Ln, 1, 1) & ";" & Mid(Ln, 2, 5) & ";" & Mid(Ln, 7, 20) & ";" & Mid(Ln, 27, 18) & ";" & Mid(Ln, 45, 18) & ";"
        Print #Fno2, Ln
        If i Mod 150000 = 0 Then Debug.Print i, Timer - Tm
        i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
Close #Fno
Close #Fno2
Debug.Print "Completed at " & Timer - Tm
End Sub`  using  FileContent` will not work with this size (2.5 Cr lines0 files. Other methods could also be explored  for improved performance.

Comment: @AhmedAU, Sir Thanks for your help. I made another for this, could you please confirm that Is it correct or not?                                                                  Sub DelimitedTextFileToArray()
Dim strFilename As String: strFilename = "C:\Users\devas\Downloads\New folder\TEST\diskostn.txt"
Dim strTextLine As String
Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
Open strFilename For Input As #iFile
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer

Comment: Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strTextLine
    'Debug.Print strTextLine
    Dim Result1 As String
    result = Left(strTextLine, 9) & ";" & Mid(strTextLine, 10, 9) & ";  " & Mid(strTextLine, 27, 22) & ";" & Mid(strTextLine, 49, 21) & ";" & Mid(strTextLine, 70, 21) & ";"
    Debug.Print result
Loop

SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
 MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

Close #iFile
End Sub

Comment: @Devas, your modified code won't work, as you have to simultaneously open two file. One source file for Input another for Output as modified delimited file. Your earlier code was in right direction but would not work as attempted to read the file content in one go. It is not possible for such big file with 2.5 Cr rows. you copy my code (tested with 2.5 Cr  rows file). modify the file name paths etc and hope it work if your file have fixed width lines as claimed by you. Also while running the code try to keep all other apps & files close, except the blank file containing the code.

Comment: since now the post is not in hold, you may edit your question using edit link below question instead of using comments..

Answer (score 0):

May try this answer tested with 2.5 Cr rows of line (with sample line provided) text files. It takes  around 550 secs to complete. Change only the  File names and paths to your requirement.

```
Option Explicit
Sub makedelimtedfile()
Dim Fno As Integer, Fno2 As Integer, i As Long
Dim FilePath As String, FilePath2 As String, xStr As String
Dim Tm As Double, Ln As String
FilePath = "C:\Users\user\desktop\Great.txt"
FilePath2 = "C:\Users\user\desktop\Great2.txt"
Fno = FreeFile
Tm = Timer
Open FilePath For Input As #Fno
Fno2 = FreeFile
Open FilePath2 For Output As #Fno2
i = 1
    Do While Not EOF(Fno)
    Line Input #Fno, Ln
        If Len(Ln) >= 62 Then
        Ln = Mid(Ln, 1, 1) & ";" & Mid(Ln, 2, 5) & ";" & Mid(Ln, 7, 20) & ";" & Mid(Ln, 27, 18) & ";" & Mid(Ln, 45, 18) & ";"
        Print #Fno2, Ln
        If i Mod 150000 = 0 Then Debug.Print i, Timer - Tm
        i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
Close #Fno
Close #Fno2
Debug.Print "Completed at " & Timer - Tm
End Sub
```